# How to search a date field in Rails using ransack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I tried to search in the date field like this :

```
<%= f.label :datestarted_cont, "Date started Contains", class: "slbl four" %>
<%= f.text_field :datestarted_cont, class: "frm-element turquoise" %>
```

But it doesn't work. I want to search for at least the year. How can I do this?

Actually im not using a separate search method. Here's my index method where I do all the stuff :

```
def index

    def serach
       params[:q][:datestarted_cont] = change_date_format(params[:q][:datestarted_cont]) if !(params[:q][:datestarted_cont]).blank?
    end

    def change_date_format(date)
        if date.include? '/'
            date_array = date.split("/")
            new_date = date_array[1]+"/"+date_array[2]+"/"+date_array[0]
            puts new_date
                return new_date
        else
                return date
        end
      end

    ############ Turn empty params[:district] to nil and params[:district] "Select District" to nil
    if params[:q] != nil
        params[:q][:district_cont] = nil_paramsdistrict(params[:q][:district_cont])
    end
    ############ Turn empty @district to nil
    @district = nil_district(@district)



    ############ Set the District. If params[:district] is not nil, @district = params[:district]. If params[:district] is nil and @district is not nil params[:district] = @district
    set_district

    if params[:commit] == "Clear"
        params[:q] = nil
    end

    @search = Awardunit.search(params[:q])
    @awardunits = @search.result.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    @unitlist = @search.result

    @units = @unitlist.size
    @disabledunits = @unitlist.where(disabled: true).size

    @leaders = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @leaders = @leaders + unit.awardleaders.size
    end

    @disabledleaders = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @disabledleaders = @disabledleaders + unit.awardleaders.where(disabled: true).size
    end

    @asstleaders = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @asstleaders = @asstleaders + unit.asstawardleaders.size
    end

    @assessors = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @assessors = @assessors + unit.assessors.size
    end

    @approvedassessors = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @approvedassessors = @approvedassessors + unit.assessors.where(approved: true).size
    end



    @members = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @members = @members + unit.members.size
    end

    @disabledmembers = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @disabledmembers = @disabledmembers + unit.members.where(disabled: true).size
    end

    @bronzemembers = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @bronzemembers = @bronzemembers + unit.members.where(currentaward: "Bronze").size
    end

    @silvermembers = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @silvermembers = @silvermembers + unit.members.where(currentaward: "Silver").size
    end

    @goldmembers = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @goldmembers = @goldmembers + unit.members.where(currentaward: "Gold").size
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.pdf do
            pdf = MemberPdf.new(@search.result.order( 'nyaaid ASC' ), view_context, Awardunit.all.size)
            send_data pdf.render, filename: "AwardUnits_List.pdf", type: "application/pdf", disposition: "inline"
        end
    end



end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.label :datestarted_cont, "Date started Contains", class: "slbl four" %>
<%= f.text_field :datestarted_cont, class: "frm-element turquoise" %>
```

**update:**

```
def index
       params[:q][:datestarted_cont] = change_date_format(params[:q][:datestarted_cont]) if !(params[:q][:datestarted_cont]).blank?

       ############ Turn empty params[:district] to nil and params[:district] "Select District" to nil
    if params[:q]!= nil
        params[:q][:district_cont] = nil_paramsdistrict(params[:q][:district_cont])
    end
    ############ Turn empty @district to nil
    @district = nil_district(@district)



    ############ Set the District. If params[:district] is not nil, @district = params[:district]. If params[:district] is nil and @district is not nil params[:district] = @district
    set_district

    if params[:commit] == "Clear"
        params[:q] = nil
    end

    @search = Awardunit.search(params[:q])
    @awardunits = @search.result.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    @unitlist = @search.result

    @units = @unitlist.size
    @disabledunits = @unitlist.where(disabled: true).size

    @leaders = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @leaders = @leaders + unit.awardleaders.size
    end

    @disabledleaders = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @disabledleaders = @disabledleaders + unit.awardleaders.where(disabled: true).size
    end

    @asstleaders = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @asstleaders = @asstleaders + unit.asstawardleaders.size
    end

    @assessors = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @assessors = @assessors + unit.assessors.size
    end

    @approvedassessors = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @approvedassessors = @approvedassessors + unit.assessors.where(approved: true).size
    end



    @members = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @members = @members + unit.members.size
    end

    @disabledmembers = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @disabledmembers = @disabledmembers + unit.members.where(disabled: true).size
    end

    @bronzemembers = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @bronzemembers = @bronzemembers + unit.members.where(currentaward: "Bronze").size
    end

    @silvermembers = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @silvermembers = @silvermembers + unit.members.where(currentaward: "Silver").size
    end

    @goldmembers = 0
    @unitlist.each do |unit|
        @goldmembers = @goldmembers + unit.members.where(currentaward: "Gold").size
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.pdf do
            pdf = MemberPdf.new(@search.result.order( 'nyaaid ASC' ), view_context, Awardunit.all.size)
            send_data pdf.render, filename: "AwardUnits_List.pdf", type: "application/pdf", disposition: "inline"
        end
    end

end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
 def change_date_format(date)
        if date.include? '/'
            date_array = date.split("/")
            new_date = date_array[1]+"/"+date_array[2]+"/"+date_array[0]
            puts new_date
                return new_date
        else
                return date
        end
      end
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me how to add the code to the search method?

Comment: @EApubs paste that line into your method what ever method you are using for search

Comment: Ah, im not using a separate search method. I just pasted the code to the controller but it won't work.

Comment: I just posted my index method.

Comment: @EApubs I have updated my answer according to your index method please check once

Comment: Sorry still not working :-( Can I get only the year or year and month?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63016/discussion-between-anusha-and-eapubs).